# PHP & MySQL Check updated rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with checking if a MySQL update statement succeeded. I want to update the users email. But they have to authorize themselfs with a token. I already used mysql_affected_rows bu when a user submits the same email as there was in the database before, the affected rows will be 0 instead of 1.
How can i check if there was a row in users with that token even when the new email is the same as before?

```
UPDATE users SET email = '".$email."' WHERE token = '".$token."'
```

Comment: Explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188232/weird-behavior-with-mysql-affected-rows-in-php

Comment: I don't unserstand what you're trying to achieve here. You want people to not be able to select the same email twice?

Comment: @Truth: My guess is that OP wants to return a *success* message if the token matches, whether or not an actual *change* was made by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This user contribution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php#104651) in the PHP Manual for `mysql_affected_rows` shows a hacky way to extract the number of rows *matched* from a call to `mysql_info()`. It *really is* hacky, though. (EDIT: There's [another version](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php#65118) in the user notes for `mysql_info` which is more general, but still hacky.)

What I would do is use a separate query:
`"select count(token) as matches from users where token = $token"`

Comment: i know thats an option but i was searching if there was a way for doing it 1 query

Comment: @user1013338: I don't think there's a way besides the two listed here. You could use a stored procedure or `mysqli_multi_query()` to gather the info in a single call to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on mysql_affected_rows, is it possible to instead depend on the return value of the mysql_query function?

For example

```
if (mysql_query ("UPDATE `users`
SET `email` = '".$email."'
WHERE `token` = '".$token."';")) { // success
} else { // fail
}
```

Comment: If no rows match, the query still succeeds. It should only fail if there's a syntax error, unknown table or column name, key violation, etc.

Comment: True, but it's not entirely clear what the OP is trying to accomplish.

If that is a problem, then I suppose you would have to attempt a SELECT query before the UPDATE query, and get the number of rows using mysql_num_rows to ensure that you get an accurate picture of matching rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `mysql_affected_rows`. It is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

For exapmle:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email = '".$email."' WHERE token = '".$token."'");
echo "Rows with that token: ".mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: OP is concerned with the case where the token matches but the email provided is not new. In this case (which OP considers a *success*), `mysql_affected_rows()` will return 0.

Comment: I guess you're wrong. He asks: "How can i check if there was a row in users with that token even when the new email is the same as before?". He says "even when the new is the same as before". If mysql_affected_rows() returns 0, so no user has that token. It is completely the opposite of what he asks for.

Comment: The manual page you linked to says: "When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query." Just because `mysql_affected_rows()` returns 0 does NOT mean there were no rows with that token. Only that there were no rows *changed* by the query.